# What is the difference between script and plug-in in Illustrator?

Tags: javascript, plugins, scripting, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I want to learn developing my own scripts (or plug-ins?) for Adobe Illustrator CS6.

What I can't understand is what is the difference between scripts and plug-ins?

I started to read a pdf guide from this page: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html but I still have no idea if they mean only scripts or they mean plug-ins too?

Answer (score 2):

Scripts are an outside programming language used to control Illustrator, typically in the  Applescript or Javascript/Extendscript languages. You can think of it almost as user actions that have been automated.

Plugins are C-based programs that are loaded by Illustrator at startup and are much more integrated with the Illustrator Internals. As a matter of fact, a lot of the standard functionality, such as the toolbar, palettes, and many effects are implemented as plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Scripting =  Programming in your artwork
Plug-ins = Additional feature/stuff in program

Answer (score 0):

A script is a programming code written in Javascript, Applescript or in VB. usually what we developed using these programming languages is the plugin. The plugin helps you to automate your work that is written in these languages. Plugins can also be written in c++ for Adobe Illustrator. For the latest version of Illustrator HTML5 and javascript is used to create plugins.